# How can SWIG read a C defined value if the type is explicitly stated?

Tags: python, c, header-files, swig

I am using SWIG (4.0.1) to generate Python modules from my C header files. SWIG processes the following define properly into the python module:

```
#define SWIG_TEST_DEFINE 3
```

(It will look like this in the generated python module my_interface.py):

```
SWIG_TEST_DEFINE = _my_interface.SWIG_TEST_DEFINE
```

but will not accept (and add to the generated python module):

```
#define SWIG_TEST_DEFINE ((int)3)
```

I am looking for a solution to make SWIG also process these constructs where a type is specified.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to change the header, you can do the following so SWIG will define the variable as `3` but the macro will still correct for C:

```c
#ifdef SWIG
#define SWIG_TEST_DEFINE 3
#else
#   define SWIG_TEST_DEFINE ((int)3)
#endif
```

If not willing to change the header, you can include it normally, then redefine the macro just for SWIG.  Below assumes `test.h` contains `#define SWIG_TEST_DEFINE ((int)3)`:

```c
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "test.h"
#undef SWIG_TEST_DEFINE
#define SWIG_TEST_DEFINE 3
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I am aware of those solutions, they are of course valid but would lead to code duplication which i wanted to avoid ;)

Comment: @ValentinForester Can’t really avoid it since swig won’t read it as is. Sometimes practicality beats purity